# select multiple rows with unique pairs, and export a random selection, for all possible pairs

Tags: r, matlab, data-manipulation, data-management

I am working with a very large dataset, and have a unique problem I haven't encountered before. This is radar data, paired with GPS points. through the radar processing, I interpolated between data points to smooth the radar image for selecting horizons. after exporting, I now have multiple points for each actual point(note the repeated lat and long entries). this is an artifact of that interpolation, and not real data. what I would like to do is select a single entry for each unique pair of lat and long, and paste it into a new data frame. I have not yet decided if I want to average the times, or randomly select, but I have not met with success in trying to pair out the unique pairs. my dilemma is that there is ~4000 unique values in each column, so a simple for loop doesn't seem to fit my needs. a sample of the top of my data is below. the full dataset is 70,000 lines.

Im decently versed in Matlab, and R. so whichever provides the simpler solution is fine by me.

**TL;DR: select each grouped pair of lat and long, and export a single entry for that group to a new file**

```
line trace  t_d C       lat       long      elev      time depth amplitude
1    0     5 0.08 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6395 60.399998 4.530 202.90558
2    0     6 0.10 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6395 60.279999 4.521 250.44923
3    0     7 0.12 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.199997 4.515 202.77191
4    0     8 0.14 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.199997 4.515 137.59879
5    0     9 0.16 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.079998 4.506  76.98897
6    0    10 0.18 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 59.959999 4.497  71.91417
7     0    11 0.20 0 58.809629 -134.194940 1759.6398 60.399998 4.530  -76.34547
8     0    12 0.22 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.520000 4.539  -71.92880
9     0    13 0.24 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.639999 4.548  -95.66286
10    0    14 0.26 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.759998 4.557 -161.85239
11    0    15 0.28 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.879997 4.566 -256.24988
12    0    16 0.30 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 61.000000 4.575 -374.82968
13    0    17 0.32 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 61.000000 4.575 -322.71951
14    0    18 0.34 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 61.000000 4.575 -270.60934
15    0    19 0.36 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 60.879997 4.566 -251.24893
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `duplicated` where `df` is your `data.frame`:

```
df[!duplicated(df[, c("lat", "long")]),]
```

If you're going to aggregate the data, try `dplyr`. E.g., you could do something like this:

```
df %>% group_by(lat, long) %>% summarise(time = mean(time))
```

Comment: Your solution was almost perfect, but its tossing some of the unique pairs, as well. Using the above data.frame, it kept line 1, but tossed line 3, which is different then line 1 and 2. any way to set how picky this is? i looked up the command. does from last control this? its not very clear.

Comment: so you want to group by lat, long, **and** elev? your question just said lat and long. in that case, just add it to the list of columns. e.g., `c("lat", "long", "elev")`

Comment: no, sorry i wasn't clear. i want to find the unique pairs of lat and long, and keep every column, but toss the repeated rows with the same lat and long pair. when i ran it, it seemed to only look at the first few decimals, but most of the differences are at the 6'th and 7th decimal. 

using the above, i would want to keep rows 1, 7, 8. but when i run it, I'm only getting rows 1 and 8.

Comment: oh, i think i found the error. some entries have the "0" and others its omitted. thats the difference thats tripping it up. let me dig back into this a bit.

thanks!

Comment: This did in fact work, my columns were shifted in relation to what i posted here, and was looking at the wrong values when i posted above. thank you so much! this was a very clear and clever fix.

Answer (score 1):

**MATLAB Implementation**

You can use `unique` with its `'rows'` option to select the first occurrence of such unique pairs  -

```
%// Assuming mat1 holds all the data
mat1 = [
1    0     5 0.08 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6395 60.399998 4.530 202.90558
2    0     6 0.10 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6395 60.279999 4.521 250.44923
3    0     7 0.12 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.199997 4.515 202.77191
4    0     8 0.14 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.199997 4.515 137.59879
5    0     9 0.16 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 60.079998 4.506  76.98897
6    0    10 0.18 0 58.809629 -134.19494 1759.6398 59.959999 4.497  71.91417
7     0    11 0.20 0 58.809629 -134.194940 1759.6398 60.399998 4.530  -76.34547
8     0    12 0.22 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.520000 4.539  -71.92880
9     0    13 0.24 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.639999 4.548  -95.66286
10    0    14 0.26 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.759998 4.557 -161.85239
11    0    15 0.28 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 60.879997 4.566 -256.24988
12    0    16 0.30 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6401 61.000000 4.575 -374.82968
13    0    17 0.32 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 61.000000 4.575 -322.71951
14    0    18 0.34 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 61.000000 4.575 -270.60934
15    0    19 0.36 0 58.809629 -134.194939 1759.6404 60.879997 4.566 -251.24893]

[~,v2,v3] = unique(mat1(:,6:7),'rows')
out = mat1(v2,:) %// desired output of unique pairs of lat and long values
```

Instead, if you are interested in the last occurrences of such unique pairs, you can use this instead, keeping rest of the code the same -

```
[~,v2,v3] = unique(mat1(:,6:7),'rows','last')
```

You also talked about using average values for "time" column I believe, for which you can use this -

```
valid1 = bsxfun(@eq,unique(v3),v3') %//'
out(:,9) = sum(bsxfun(@times,mat1(:,9)',valid1),2)./sum(valid1,2) %//' desired output with average values for "time"
```

Comment: Clever solution, but It's not quite working. the output was missing large swaths of data that is unique.. it seems to not be going out far enough in the precision. can you control how far it looks before deciding what to delete?

Comment: @Scandela1986 Could you check back again, because it seems you made some changes/corrections looking at your comments for the other solution?

Comment: @Divaker i did mis-type in my response initially, but i never got your code to work.. each time i ran it, it seems to pick a different set of unique values. it seemed to be getting stuck on the precision, and without going far enough it didn't select the same values. Ill also admit, while i decent at matlab, i generally work in R, so i was predisposed to take the R solution when it worked.  Thank you for working on this though, I've been a long time lurker on stack overflow, and this was my first time posting a question. your prompt response was very helpful.

Comment: @Scandela1986 That's okay really. You were good to go with a solution that worked for you is really the most important thing. Good luck!